# Pine Script assign value of first bar to global variable and use for every further bar

Tags: pine-script

I need `startValue` to be the close price of first bar (in this case 2020-12-11), but  `startValue` has wrong value, however permanent (looks like close[30] from first bar).

```
// inputs
show_label = input(true, "Show labels")

show1 = input(true, "targetVV", inline="targetVV")
src1 = input(hlc3, "", type=input.source, inline="targetVV")
color1 = input(#f6c309, "", inline="targetVV")
date1 = input(title="Date", type=input.time, defval=timestamp("2020-12-11T00:00+00:00"), inline="targetVV")

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// function to calculate targetVV
    
var startValue = close[0]

f_avwap(src, date) =>
    start = time >= date and time[1] < date
    sumSrc = src * volume
    sumVol = volume
    sumSrc := start ? sumSrc : sumSrc + sumSrc[1]
    sumVol := start ? sumVol : sumVol + sumVol[1]
    sumSrc / sumVol + startValue ()
    
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// plot targetVV

plot(show1 ? f_avwap(src1, date1) : na, color=color1, title="targetVV")

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// plot labels
plotshape(show_label and show1 ? time >= date1 and time[1] < date1 : na, text='targetVV',
   textcolor=color.white, color=color.new(color1, 35), location=location.belowbar, style=shape.labelup, size=size.small)
```

I tried `var startValue = close`, same result

Another option was

```
count = array.new_float()
for i = 0 to 1000
    array.push(count, 0)

f_updateStartValue() =>
    price = close[array.pop(count)]
    price

f_avwap(src, date) =>
    start = time >= date and time[1] < date
    sumSrc = src * volume
    sumVol = volume
    sumSrc := start ? sumSrc : sumSrc + sumSrc[1]
    sumVol := start ? sumVol : sumVol + sumVol[1]
    sumSrc / sumVol + f_updateStartValue()
```

but it seems to reset array every bar and provides close of current bar, not the first bar

if I use `var` count = array.new_float(), script does not work at all

if I hardcode value to `startValue` like `startValue = 24`, it works great.

Any ideas on how to store first bar close value in order to apply in all other bars?

Answer (score 0):

```
firstBar = na(close[1])
firstBarClose = ta.valuewhen(firstBar, close, 0)
```

***Pine Script version=5***

Comment: This results in the exactly same result as my first option 'var startValue = close[0]
'